# Fitting exponentially modified gaussian to a data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to fit an exponentially modified gaussian to my data. It is not giving any error, but the resulting plot I get is just a straight line parallel to x axis. Obviously, the program did not fit the curve. I could not figure out what the problem is! Can anyone help me to properly modify the code to perform the curve fit. Following is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import exponnorm
data = np.genfromtxt("Data.dat", delimiter='\t')
indices = np.where(data[:,1]==922)
data_922 = data[indices]
x_922 = data_922[:,1]
Tofs = data_922[:,8]
plt.figure(1)
y, bin_borders, _ = plt.hist(Tofs, bins=100, label='histogram')
x = (bin_borders[:-1] + bin_borders[1:])/ 2
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x, exponnorm.pdf(y,K))
plt.show()
```

About my data: I am new in stackoverflow. I don't find a way to attach the data. My data has 10 columns and 400 rows. As you see in the code, I try to extract those rows with values 922 in the first column. Then I am trying to fit the data in 8th column. I copy paste the data here.

Any suggestions of better method to fit Exponentially modified Gaussian will also be great.

EDIT: I was doing something wrong. `plt.plot(x, exponnorm.pdf(x,y))` should be `plt.plot(x, exponnorm.pdf(y,K))`. Now I am confused, how to find out K!!!

[enter link description here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponnorm.html)

```
1   922 19189.109481016 -270.6  922 21541.107907252 -265.4  922 37979.426419287 -223.8

2   922 14079.723490316 -283.6  922 21058.637648168 -265.4  922 38788.976774951 -221.2

3   922 18514.863008888 -273.2  922 20565.45124418  -268    922 39367.330635382 -218.6

4   922 26273.503137497 -252.4  922 27003.73310164  -249.8  922 38145.179798139 -221.2

5   922 18234.10160971  -273.2  922 21377.434029357 -265.4  922 40207.318885913 -216

6   922 13585.923804982 -286.2  922 21809.537773165 -265.4  922 39656.603350441 -218.6

7   922 12894.566880222 -288.8  922 20627.508056691 -268    922 37544.441437487 -223.8

8   922 18117.327712792 -273.2  922 19638.819453111 -270.6  922 37954.264708019 -223.8

9   922 18161.12130049  -273.2  922 20187.00365343  -268    922 39654.083548949 -218.6

10  922 16303.257921539 -278.4  922 21087.822642192 -265.4  922 38958.294725131 -221.2

11  922 11615.235062421 -291.4  922 21754.275449702 -265.4  922 38919.978977862 -221.2

12  922 19986.243194452 -270.6  922 21407.866747453 -265.4  922 39300.614378451 -218.6

13  922 15639.699715853 -281    922 21156.188627953 -265.4  922 38315.911925883 -221.2

14  922 17713.909834329 -275.8  922 21482.766601704 -265.4  922 38617.319588652 -221.2

15  922 11039.744171804 -291.4  922 20482.440151535 -268    922 38519.137083575 -221.2

16  922 19003.530755129 -270.6  922 21199.216873558 -265.4  922 38700.784469912 -221.2

17  922 26939.996270505 -252.4  922 27732.96841359  -249.8  922 39509.191233456 -218.6

18  922 26473.351448214 -252.4  922 27135.630729142 -249.8  922 37521.152835613 -223.8

19  922 12836.007894783 -288.8  922 19250.68422642  -270.6  922 37227.766667897 -223.8

20  922 17545.530117185 -275.8  922 18838.471293654 -273.2  922 38588.240747654 -221.2

21  922 19579.320509937 -270.6  922 21039.320509936 -265.4  922 38125.948419189 -221.2

22  922 27141.980286838 -249.8  922 27846.548391894 -249.8  922 38744.025532992 -221.2

23  922 46123.459159716 -200.4  922 46436.135026598 -200.4  922 47098.494006722 -197.8

24  922 17447.352193898 -275.8  922 20219.290934972 -268    922 38161.971790639 -221.2

25  922 11546.390848303 -291.4  922 17869.920260069 -275.8  922 38498.767882175 -221.2

26  922 22410.952749675 -262.8  922 23658.011573203 -260.2  922 36902.08537245  -226.4

27  922 17142.791954461 -275.8  922 21433.040630217 -265.4  922 39792.818876512 -218.6

28  922 10978.343416343 -294    922 19977.534157198 -270.6  922 39737.912206389 -218.6

29  922 17560.818469021 -275.8  922 19760.818469019 -270.6  922 38749.638266088 -221.2

30  922 41903.665324908 -213.4  922 42274.896383787 -210.8  922 43275.531232826 -208.2

31  922 15385.754028709 -281    922 21171.636381646 -265.4  922 40453.399240981 -216

32  922 12227.329250537 -288.8  922 22697.545966962 -262.8  922 39172.297509188 -218.6

33  922 13402.35080407  -286.2  922 20324.333889924 -268    922 37846.694311044 -223.8

34  922 14240.649234071 -283.6  922 19343.490915935 -270.6  922 39010.462411888 -218.6

35  922 16186.432263606 -278.4  922 20992.314616543 -268    922 38688.140740893 -221.2

36  922 12222.446066768 -288.8  922 21035.6416498   -265.4  922 39161.539644778 -218.6

37  922 12157.775400469 -288.8  922 19570.716576939 -270.6  922 38620.485673185 -221.2

38  922 17029.238496292 -275.8  922 19743.755498514 -270.6  922 39504.427645159 -218.6

39  922 15821.240584605 -281    922 19155.358231662 -270.6  922 39602.23567916  -218.6

40  922 10582.225773262 -294    922 19508.557765614 -270.6  922 38498.505470459 -221.2

41  922 17690.580365779 -275.8  922 19292.933306954 -270.6  922 39438.501834978 -218.6

42  922 8594.9788213337 -299.2  922 17457.331762514 -275.8  922 38932.828527992 -221.2

43  922 19332.428193377 -270.6  922 21202.259715689 -265.4  922 38530.035207401 -221.2

44  922 11962.896993471 -291.4  922 21068.068388929 -265.4  922 38174.93322643  -221.2

45  922 13354.270074111 -286.2  922 19958.975956462 -270.6  922 38708.167694719 -221.2

46  922 13023.931782609 -286.2  922 19601.144333567 -270.6  922 39187.52994803  -218.6

47  922 8749.1660117312 -299.2  922 20164.159958382 -268    922 39597.185913813 -218.6

48  922 12966.66693335  -288.8  922 21886.666933347 -265.4  922 37814.156632053 -223.8

49  922 10070.193829019 -294    922 20840.612167812 -268    922 39335.875285423 -218.6

50  922 9973.2141035199 -296.6  922 22380.722149124 -262.8  922 39463.769639987 -218.6

51  922 16649.837005577 -278.4  922 21106.353831991 -265.4  922 38991.907467781 -221.2

52  922 18992.979832604 -273.2  922 21454.163120834 -265.4  922 38127.753969727 -221.2

53  922 12609.476518618 -288.8  922 19087.512082223 -270.6  922 38024.104621615 -221.2

54  922 14984.455069172 -283.6  922 19719.45008129  -270.6  922 38722.950281657 -221.2

55  922 9517.5431380981 -296.6  922 20411.523068441 -268    922 38542.153134368 -221.2

56  922 13775.169969085 -286.2  922 19126.934674967 -270.6  922 39515.955968225 -218.6

57  922 15561.740927295 -281    922 21154.847275645 -265.4  922 38587.78436648  -221.2

58  922 33592.753038935 -234.2  922 34155.706455529 -231.6  922 38190.215502862 -221.2

59  922 16992.501257413 -278.4  922 18870.353337038 -273.2  922 39459.233274913 -218.6

60  922 11104.727041142 -291.4  922 19943.550570554 -270.6  922 37879.305440444 -223.8

61  922 16118.077912534 -278.4  922 20281.132206284 -268    922 38898.032832024 -221.2

62  922 16964.494393147 -278.4  922 20426.159333256 -268    922 38682.838556659 -221.2

63  922 12054.37286626  -288.8  922 22597.883675606 -262.8  922 37718.473839444 -223.8

64  922 16949.109977307 -278.4  922 19222.243921252 -270.6  922 39806.16156526  -218.6

65  922 13264.779334846 -286.2  922 20398.896981904 -268    922 37722.680599115 -223.8

66  922 15924.942366387 -281    922 21397.406877876 -265.4  922 38216.940414169 -221.2

67  922 14028.969228098 -283.6  922 20764.956713544 -268    922 37151.504072455 -223.8

68  922 13979.109833009 -286.2  922 19820.321527251 -270.6  922 38726.609318114 -221.2

69  922 11670.846520793 -291.4  922 21269.302012082 -265.4  922 39205.658243702 -218.6

70  922 15262.990046498 -281    922 19502.990046496 -270.6  922 39753.367268214 -218.6

71  922 20331.519949276 -268    922 21730.343478686 -265.4  922 39114.29496463  -218.6

72  922 13478.475723413 -286.2  922 20032.613111546 -268    922 37859.819524797 -223.8

73  922 21766.1188931   -265.4  922 22890.892492249 -262.8  922 40016.248128589 -216

74  922 23065.128433478 -260.2  922 24509.683031378 -257.6  922 37910.573277025 -223.8

75  922 12696.989192288 -288.8  922 19393.360996583 -270.6  922 38467.52050084  -221.2

76  922 17528.085230248 -275.8  922 22281.026406714 -262.8  922 39433.172517568 -218.6

77  922 11948.952064672 -291.4  922 21882.189590574 -265.4  922 39504.250174407 -218.6

78  922 14768.006931441 -283.6  922 19426.812052638 -270.6  922 38794.848157794 -221.2

79  922 13845.023697549 -286.2  922 20551.279627008 -268    922 
38240.126213745 -221.2

80  922 14862.651325531 -283.6  922 18808.970219959 -273.2  922 38652.717749644 -221.2

81  922 15556.113850681 -281    922 18840.819733032 -273.2  922 39262.826930474 -218.6

82  922 21663.518740699 -265.4  922 23016.013850202 -260.2  922 37264.210383471 -223.8

83  922 16484.05714859  -278.4  922 20286.968111624 -268    922 37346.751740684 -223.8

84  922 17778.559939091 -275.8  922 21682.851013039 -265.4  922 38282.956734956 -221.2

85  922 13957.839466234 -286.2  922 20327.251230938 -268    922 38577.955876939 -221.2

86  922 15773.796070317 -281    922 20025.560776196 -268    922 39470.712110765 -218.6

87  922 13596.395088714 -286.2  922 20161.24433366  -268    922 39572.322533081 -218.6

88  922 16409.810096842 -278.4  922 22751.492444221 -262.8  922 39639.029994181 -218.6

89  922 13195.068901808 -286.2  922 22515.05188116  -262.8  922 38175.905950368 -221.2

90  922 18034.153715903 -273.2  922 20122.556851853 -268    922 39100.992718812 -218.6

91  922 10680.095531038 -294    922 19580.095531038 -270.6  922 39847.729045572 -218.6

92  922 14410.810064155 -283.6  922 21402.05318059  -265.4  922 39139.400736711 -218.6

93  922 15450.409658921 -281    922 20982.499314852 -268    922 38504.103101556 -221.2

94  922 19620.331995027 -270.6  922 21829.949180527 -265.4  922 36011.1879986   -226.4

95  922 15236.470588239 -281    922 20114.691287285 -268    922 38820.184042785 -221.2

96  922 14394.548992869 -283.6  922 19472.649232216 -270.6  922 38948.345779381 -221.2

97  922 15576.798620265 -281    922 21729.764740485 -265.4  922 37214.359062005 -223.8

98  922 20127.092387221 -268    922 21561.468436316 -265.4  922 40828.166076615 -216

99  922 11622.10381397  -291.4  922 20667.330841147 -268    922 38067.485024844 -221.2

100 922 14951.700149486 -283.6  922 19668.17073772  -270.6  922 39334.278762306 -218.6

101 922 14183.008916418 -283.6  922 20873.618370797 -268    922 38518.384387338 -221.2

102 922 19023.503425142 -270.6  922 21311.018668174 -265.4  922 37613.835938289 -223.8

103 922 18113.275117214 -273.2  922 20050.922176036 -268    922 38639.769701938 -221.2

104 922 23923.463609897 -260.2  922 25056.593921388 -255    922 38596.674943347 -221.2

105 922 15474.502079904 -281    922 20826.911255736 -268    922 38423.961317259 -221.2

106 922 19651.228957424 -270.6  922 23665.346604479 -260.2  922 37690.441768552 -223.8

107 922 18475.191794363 -273.2  922 20200.208436212 -268    922 39207.094717376 -218.6

108 922 13855.635544667 -286.2  922 18695.635544667 -273.2  922 39327.579602081 -218.6

109 922 12857.021714882 -288.8  922 20855.483635786 -268    922 38632.461878366 -221.2

110 922 45914.809510386 -203    922 46248.49894498  -200.4  922 46903.745859778 -200.4

111 922 21945.491170803 -265.4  922 23016.674044153 -260.2  922 39911.437841055 -218.6

112 922 15765.062376713 -281    922 20650.265880754 -268    922 39883.230682072 -218.6

113 922 15984.511970748 -281    922 19005.350183473 -270.6  922 37503.730649463 -223.8

114 922 16619.415866289 -278.4  922 20489.58427008  -268    922 38421.45776691  -221.2

115 922 17889.054831493 -275.8  922 20126.31631727  -268    922 38049.724611549 -221.2

116 922 21745.575909689 -265.4  922 22792.795128611 -262.8  922 39958.564606328 -218.6

117 922 16786.593704424 -278.4  922 18666.685050765 -273.2  922 38236.171624081 -221.2

118 922 21602.354883411 -265.4  922 23598.549016295 -260.2  922 38158.838292399 -221.2

119 922 20592.207244922 -268    922 21754.275442712 -265.4  922 38574.92365296  -221.2

120 922 16064.217916434 -278.4  922 20966.530269219 -268    922 38645.719506645 -221.2

121 922 14762.811415305 -283.6  922 19393.399650597 -270.6  922 39918.140208007 -218.6

122 922 25253.504255734 -255    922 26314.508920586 -252.4  922 37520.439544206 -223.8

123 922 17209.13404231  -275.8  922 20265.431400656 -268    922 40096.151904562 -216

124 922 11673.455200337 -291.4  922 17168.749317986 -275.8  922 39881.505241524 -218.6

125 922 16156.505623537 -278.4  922 19162.387976476 -270.6  922 38207.801507297 -221.2

126 922 10862.669204291 -294    922 21907.375086643 -265.4  922 40345.952009712 -216

127 922 10496.406032616 -294    922 18099.094063739 -273.2  922 37242.579692986 -223.8

128 922 12563.727412162 -288.8  922 21058.009891479 -265.4  922 39514.338985875 -218.6

129 922 13769.857401868 -286.2  922 18379.317423877 -273.2  922 39722.400794874 -218.6

130 922 33482.317857667 -234.2  922 33948.822869127 -234.2  922 40663.505459434 -216

131 922 12466.627766758 -288.8  922 21361.67198558  -265.4  922 38741.83325081  -221.2

132 922 17092.517451651 -275.8  922 19689.040356089 -270.6  922 38630.440558074 -221.2

133 922 15014.303564686 -281    922 19396.832560846 -270.6  922 39308.200939032 -218.6

134 922 24765.213522793 -257.6  922 25568.639217758 -255    922 40127.379951335 -216

135 922 12836.142208502 -288.8  922 19168.20683537  -270.6  922 39477.093390103 -218.6

136 922 11586.837190201 -291.4  922 19650.461960458 -270.6  922 38877.544646995 -221.2

137 922 13800.168374765 -286.2  922 17633.045124909 -275.8  922 37156.981298783 -223.8

138 922 12718.021373035 -288.8  922 18351.435764432 -273.2  922 38575.565423929 -221.2

139 922 10077.867934453 -294    922 21954.027253282 -265.4  922 37423.325626632 -223.8

140 922 12288.906264841 -288.8  922 19191.259206017 -270.6  922 39264.779775395 -218.6

141 922 33004.797914589 -234.2  922 33479.707603288 -234.2  922 37829.426324626 -223.8

142 922 24057.607183003 -257.6  922 25279.172714987 -255    922 38057.592727131 -221.2

143 922 23682.660704287 -260.2  922 24559.938287077 -257.6  922 39603.797451976 -218.6

144 922 14177.097911183 -283.6  922 20015.043089469 -268    922 39117.208334655 -218.6

145 922 16972.338545825 -278.4  922 21551.698237638 -265.4  922 39105.635671424 -218.6

146 922 13689.951183723 -286.2  922 17172.862955645 -275.8  922 39937.805306574 -218.6

147 922 14515.000040457 -283.6  922 20393.823569866 -268    922 39367.696039251 -218.6

148 922 22843.675263371 -262.8  922 24014.114448638 -257.6  922 39470.071023659 -218.6

149 922 15017.56579821  -281    922 19225.801092326 -270.6  922 39710.541081819 -218.6

150 922 24537.840601739 -257.6  922 25931.649335686 -255    922 36383.748592861 -226.4

151 922 18044.179651962 -273.2  922 20543.003181372 -268    922 39589.630034418 -218.6

152 922 24014.708625812 -257.6  922 24871.903367206 -257.6  922 39669.101979214 -218.6

153 922 12713.53417975  -288.8  922 19574.947662033 -270.6  922 39024.719104036 -218.6

154 922 20501.413768236 -268    922 22807.420956791 -262.8  922 40099.928245074 -216

155 922 17311.764771359 -275.8  922 19021.668320393 -270.6  922 37281.012807631 -223.8

156 922 16414.617075143 -278.4  922 21289.7282753   -265.4  922 39640.820652182 -218.6

157 922 22310.436830724 -262.8  922 23440.515134302 -260.2  922 39224.153208398 -218.6

158 922 13883.453766215 -286.2  922 20282.838639409 -268    922 39271.99192732  -218.6

159 922 14146.422927901 -283.6  922 21031.533345306 -265.4  922 38433.435036905 -221.2

160 922 18279.050296013 -273.2  922 20251.316099662 -268    922 38435.873798264 -221.2

161 922 22780.918768585 -262.8  922 23690.33053329  -260.2  922 38084.746799382 -221.2

162 922 19351.462083177 -270.6  922 20799.03097369  -268    922 39035.27185365  -218.6

163 922 17181.628722432 -275.8  922 18752.216957725 -273.2  922 38572.905470196 -221.2

164 922 13683.936144646 -286.2  922 19523.936144645 -270.6  922 37583.608099411 -223.8

165 922 14454.336175917 -283.6  922 21177.74568454  -265.4  922 39523.423896793 -218.6

166 922 15178.69104407  -281    922 19379.867514656 -270.6  922 37698.854275935 -223.8

167 922 24962.979887384 -257.6  922 26041.484593027 -252.4  922 39589.690550316 -218.6

168 922 13137.828597807 -286.2  922 21031.946244864 -265.4  922 38852.973747629 -221.2

169 922 13960.108686858 -286.2  922 22427.167510384 -262.8  922 39288.063016228 -218.6

170 922 23274.256115185 -260.2  922 24359.030809358 -257.6  922 39472.259612452 -218.6

171 922 21043.197307605 -265.4  922 22409.079660545 -262.8  922 40256.65581288  -216

172 922 16979.997108829 -278.4  922 19216.489708243 -270.6  922 37341.276484313 -223.8

173 922 13488.302566395 -286.2  922 20347.138541575 -268    922 37979.679565782 -223.8

174 922 15611.569877809 -281    922 21336.275760158 -265.4  922 38896.401315675 -221.2

175 922 13899.743833029 -286.2  922 19667.979127146 -270.6  922 38015.963206354 -221.2

176 922 14105.883585387 -283.6  922 19288.236526562 -270.6  922 38322.377507893 -221.2

177 922 11932.198731837 -291.4  922 20200.434025954 -268    922 40558.449396365 -216

178 922 22127.302377353 -262.8  922 23230.990922135 -260.2  922 39676.671214373 -218.6

179 922 35018.584690127 -229    922 35465.568644372 -229    922 40620.8843263   -216

180 922 13171.580469797 -286.2  922 17090.893702961 -275.8  922 38688.258220684 -221.2

181 922 14524.770555528 -283.6  922 21468.889390172 -265.4  922 38331.907498252 -221.2

182 922 18522.331323778 -273.2  922 19958.801912012 -270.6  922 38480.987850248 -221.2

183 922 17753.615088183 -275.8  922 21080.67391171  -265.4  922 39498.499430402 -218.6

184 922 11043.151283428 -291.4  922 19447.857165782 -270.6  922 38681.224108506 -221.2

185 922 13092.079034162 -286.2  922 19960.95427577  -270.6  922 39096.038744912 -218.6

186 922 19751.047427192 -270.6  922 21114.885733178 -265.4  922 38461.868752262 -221.2

187 922 18873.14639443  -273.2  922 20460.466424806 -268    922 39843.833536656 -218.6

188 922 15770.204553203 -281    922 20478.809617554 -268    922 38628.998614713 -221.2

189 922 14662.614259027 -283.6  922 21172.093770811 -265.4  922 39175.461537086 -218.6

190 922 23394.521703609 -260.2  922 24173.497376146 -257.6  922 38585.333490791 -221.2

191 922 19980.092335734 -270.6  922 21499.941850485 -265.4  922 39842.860993741 -218.6

192 922 15308.346426065 -281    922 18142.069526926 -273.2  922 37421.091725167 -223.8

193 922 18735.07692652  -273.2  922 20428.696461993 -268    922 38733.516332102 -221.2

194 922 19607.261765632 -270.6  922 21424.908824454 -265.4  922 38684.788847783 -221.2

195 922 18707.187936024 -273.2  922 21764.884049831 -265.4  922 39408.73175627  -218.6

196 922 26589.191824069 -252.4  922 27452.155630033 -249.8  922 37286.982989086 -223.8

197 922 14446.246571037 -283.6  922 19862.71715927  -270.6  922 38438.947019407 -221.2

198 922 20192.032860307 -268    922 22350.303567797 -262.8  922 38662.650990446 -221.2

199 922 16743.705102974 -278.4  922 21755.830499401 -265.4  922 38229.612835868 -221.2

200 922 13064.975310998 -286.2  922 18623.856051878 -273.2  922 38693.450024781 -221.2

201 1222    4634.5594634066 -309.6  1222    5648.6771104653 -307    1222    20969.793805765 -268

202 1222    4664.2664850226 -309.6  1222    5713.3155160498 -307    1222    22062.956510825 -262.8

203 1222    17502.250003759 -275.8  1222    17934.959021161 -275.8  1222    21038.300438151 -265.4

204 1222    11943.722702845 -291.4  1222    12539.430594868 -288.8  1222    21676.486045746 -265.4

205 1222    6393.5275794691 -304.4  1222    7323.7896093534 -301.8  1222    21528.148551327 -265.4

206 1222    8190.5719954334 -299.2  1222    8927.0634796124 -299.2  1222    22808.299659806 -262.8

207 1222    6756.9906564481 -304.4  1222    7665.6373457683 -301.8  1222    21376.241902178 -265.4

208 1222    3851.9943917718 -312.2  1222    4712.6590603422 -309.6  1222    21796.465991411 -265.4

209 1222    13029.496506292 -286.2  1222    13515.547326964 -286.2  1222    20612.129556241 -268
```

Comment: please modify the question and specify the variable you want to fit (X and Y), and provide a picture of the plot by matplotlib that you want to fit on.

Comment: Where in the code is your actual fit? You're asking about fitting, but I only see `import curve_fit`, no actual fitting code.

Comment: You've tagged this question with both python3 and python2. Which one is it? And since this is most likely Python version independent, it's better to remove both these tags. There is, however, a [scipy] tag which would have been more useful.